# Rails where to create :through object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, has-many-through

Hi I`m learning has_many :through and I have a association like this.

student:

```
has_many :subjects, through: :participations
has_many :participations
```

subject:

```
has_many :students, through: :participations
has_many :participations
belongs_to :student
```

participation:

```
belongs_to :student
belongs_to :subject
```

The `student` subjects are updated through checkboxes in update view:

```
= f.association :subjecs, label_method: :title, value_method: :id, label: 'Subjects', as: :check_boxes
```

And I went so far :( My student have subjects id, but it can`t get them since no participation is created.

My update action:

```
def create
  student = Student.new(student_params)
  if student.save
    redirect_to students_path
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

My question is when should I create participation object, and where is the appropriate place for the function ?

Comment: This actually looks OK. You shouldn't need to manually create `Participations` in the form. Is it possible your typo on the spelling of `:subjecTs` is the problem?

Comment: I will look to it more careful, thnx for pointing that it looks ok, it is vital info form me :)

Answer (score 2):

When you have a [`has_many`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many) relationship, you actually get a bunch of methods which can help you.

One of these is `association_singular_ids`- which if you populate it correctly, will automatically create the associative data you need.

[image]

The way to do this will be to use the following:

```
#app/views/students/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_check_boxes :subject_ids, Subject.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I know you're using `f.association` (which is built through `simple_form`) - you'll be much better suited to using [`collection_check_boxes`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_check_boxes) (it even explains an example of what you're having problems with).

You shouldn't need to pass the params or anything - and because your `participations` model acts as a join, it should be populated automatically if you use the above code.

---

[**HABTM**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

You may also wish to look at `has_and_belongs_to_many`:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :subjects
end

#app/models/subject.rb
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :students
end

#join table - students_subjects
```

This is often preferred over `has_many :through` because it requires less maintenance (as described in the link above).

---

**Nested Attributes**

Finally, to give you some more perspective, you'll need to know about the *nested attributes* aspect of Rails.

I originally thought your answer would be that you're not using [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), but I don't think so now. Nonetheless, you'll still gain benefit from knowing about it.

--

One of the reasons you'd use `has_many through` would be to populate the join model with other attributes. HABTM does not allow this; because `has_many :through` has a join model (in your case `participations`), it allows you to add extra attributes into it.

As such, if you're looking to *change* any of those attributes, you'll need to pass them through your various models:

```
#app/models/student.rb
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations
   has_many :subjects, through: :participations
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :participations
end

#app/models/participation.rb
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
   belongs_to :subject
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
end

#app/models/subject.rb
class Subject< ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :participations
   has_many :students, through: :participations 
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/students_controller.rb
class StudentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
     @student = Student.new
     @student.participations.build
   end

   def create
      @student = Student.new student_params
      @student.save
   end

   private

   def student_params
      params.require(:student).permit(:student, :params, participations_attributes: [subject_attributes:[]])
   end
end
```

This should allow you to use the following:

```
#app/views/students/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :participations do |p| %>
      <%= p.text_field :name %>
      <%= p.collection_check_boxes :subject_id, Subject.all, :id, :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Rich, this was a really comprehensive answer. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I didn`t permited the chenge od subject_ids in the student controller:

```
params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name, subject_ids: [])
```